# php DatePeriod пропадают месяца

Tags: php, datetime

Такой странный вопрос. Мне нужно получить все месяца (первый день месяца и последний день месяца) за 11 месяцев (для создания графиков). Но периодически "пропадают" месяца. В данный момент пропал апрель.
Пример кода

```
$date = new DateTime('-11 month');
$lastYearDate = $date->format('Y-m-d ');
$from = new DateTime($lastYearDate);
$to = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d 00:01"));

$period = new DatePeriod($from, new DateInterval('P1D'), $to);


$lastYearMonth = $date->format('Y-m-d');
$from = new DateTime($lastYearMonth);
$to = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));

$period = new DatePeriod($from, new DateInterval('P32D'), $to);

$arrayOfMonth = array_map(
    function ($item) {
        $dateOfMonth = array();
        $dateOfMonth['year'] = $item->format('Y');
        $dateOfMonth['month'] = $item->format('m');
        $dateOfMonth['first_days'] = $item->format('Y-m-01');
        $dateOfMonth['last_days'] = $item->format('Y-m-t');

        return $dateOfMonth;
    },
    iterator_to_array($period)
);
```

Вот вывод массива `arrayOfMonth`:

```
array(11) { 
    [0]=> array(4) { ["year"]=> string(4) "2017" ["month"]=> string(2) "06" ["first_days"]=> string(10) "2017-06-01" ["last_days"]=> string(10) "2017-06-30" } 
    [1]=> array(4) { ["year"]=> string(4) "2017" ["month"]=> string(2) "07" ["first_days"]=> string(10) "2017-07-01" ["last_days"]=> string(10) "2017-07-31" } 
    [2]=> array(4) { ["year"]=> string(4) "2017" ["month"]=> string(2) "08" ["first_days"]=> string(10) "2017-08-01" ["last_days"]=> string(10) "2017-08-31" } 
    [3]=> array(4) { ["year"]=> string(4) "2017" ["month"]=> string(2) "09" ["first_days"]=> string(10) "2017-09-01" ["last_days"]=> string(10) "2017-09-30" } 
    [4]=> array(4) { ["year"]=> string(4) "2017" ["month"]=> string(2) "10" ["first_days"]=> string(10) "2017-10-01" ["last_days"]=> string(10) "2017-10-31" } 
    [5]=> array(4) { ["year"]=> string(4) "2017" ["month"]=> string(2) "11" ["first_days"]=> string(10) "2017-11-01" ["last_days"]=> string(10) "2017-11-30" } 
    [6]=> array(4) { ["year"]=> string(4) "2017" ["month"]=> string(2) "12" ["first_days"]=> string(10) "2017-12-01" ["last_days"]=> string(10) "2017-12-31" } 
    [7]=> array(4) { ["year"]=> string(4) "2018" ["month"]=> string(2) "01" ["first_days"]=> string(10) "2018-01-01" ["last_days"]=> string(10) "2018-01-31" } 
    [8]=> array(4) { ["year"]=> string(4) "2018" ["month"]=> string(2) "02" ["first_days"]=> string(10) "2018-02-01" ["last_days"]=> string(10) "2018-02-28" } 
    [9]=> array(4) { ["year"]=> string(4) "2018" ["month"]=> string(2) "03" ["first_days"]=> string(10) "2018-03-01" ["last_days"]=> string(10) "2018-03-31" } 
    [10]=> array(4) { ["year"]=> string(4) "2018" ["month"]=> string(2) "05" ["first_days"]=> string(10) "2018-05-01" ["last_days"]=> string(10) "2018-05-31" } 
}
```

Почему получается так, что после марта идёт май?

Comment: Почему период 32 дня, а не 1 месяц?

Comment: @vp_arth ну вы еще спросите, почему бы просто по месяцу не прибавлять в цикле, а писать 20 строк кода :)

Comment: зы: получается что после марта идем май, потому что февраль с его 30 днями просто "провалился" внутрь интервала в 32 дня

Comment: Чтобы понять в чём проблема, всего-то нужно увидеть актуальные даты итератора: `$dateOfMonth['actual'] = $item->format('Y-m-d')`

Comment: @vp_arth в смысле? что изменится в удобством получения? `format("t")` так и останется как тут в коде.

Comment: Да я не понял, про "прибавлять в цикле". Думал предлагаешь без DateTime/DateInterval обойтись.

Comment: @vp_arth именно это и предлагал (: c `DateTime`, конечно, но без интервалов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используется некорректный интервал в 32 дня.

```
<?php

$dt = new \DateTime();
$month = new \DateInterval('P1M');
for ($i = 0; $i < 12; ++$i) {
    echo $dt->format('Y-m-01 - Y-m-t')."\n";
    $dt->add($month);
}
```

> 2018-05-01 - 2018-05-31
>   2018-06-01 - 2018-06-30
>   2018-07-01 - 2018-07-31
>   2018-08-01 - 2018-08-31
>   2018-09-01 - 2018-09-30
>   2018-10-01 - 2018-10-31
>   2018-11-01 - 2018-11-30
>   2018-12-01 - 2018-12-31
>   2019-01-01 - 2019-01-31
>   2019-02-01 - 2019-02-28
>   2019-03-01 - 2019-03-31
>   2019-04-01 - 2019-04-30

Comment: Спасибо.
Пока сильно код не переписывал, а просто изменил P1D и P32D на P1M и апрель нашёлся. Но обязательно упрощу код в соответствии с вашими рекомендациями. А то сильно я что-то намудрил

Comment: Вообще, весь код у вас до строчки `$lastYearMonth` выглядит лишним.

Answer (score 1):

вариант без использования `DateInterval`, для коллекции.

```
$mcount = 11;
$result =  array_map(function($m){
                 return (new DateTime("-$m month"))->format("Y-m-01  -  Y-m-t\n");
              }, range($mcount , 0));

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Никогда не нравился мне этот strtotime =) Слишком он умный